# Eventbrite event_search not reporting capacity

Tags: eventbrite

I'm using Eventbrite's [event_search](http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/events/event_search/) to display upcoming events, along with some idea of remaining tickets.  The problem is, event_search is reporting capacity = 0 for all events.
When I use [organizer_list_events](http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/organizers/organizer_list_events/) I can see the correct capacities, but I'd rather not use that method as I don't want to display or have to filter past and 'draft' events.
Am I missing something?  Is there another way to retrieve event capacity?

Answer (score 0):

The V1 event_search method only retrieves publicly available date, of which capacity is not. Capacity is considered private data that is only accessible to the administrators of the event, which is why you can get that data with the organizer_list_events method.

Y0u could move up to the V3 method User Owned Events and pass in the 'status' parameter to 'live' in order to only get the upcoming events.